# Proof strategy - Stirling numbers formula

Tags: elementary-number-theory, stirling-numbers

I need to prove such a formula:

$$
{n\brace k-1}\cdot{n\brace k+1}\leqslant{n\brace k}^2
$$
Where {} are Stirling numbers of the second kind. 
(number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets).

I tried to figure out some combinatorial proof, but failed.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: A sequence $c_n$ is called discrete log-concave if $c_n^2 \geqslant c_{n-1} c_{n+1}$. 

This [article](http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/040_4_0693.pdf) by Sibuya proves the discrete log-concavity for Stirling numbers.

Comment: Possibly related: [An Inequality Involving Bell Numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67988/2370)

Comment: There is a fairly short but very non-combinatorial proof in Herbert S. Wilf’s *generatingfunctionology*, which may be downloaded [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) as a hyperlinked PDF. The desired result is Corollary 4.5.3. Do you just need a proof, or do you specifically want t combinatorial proof?

Comment: Combinatorial proof was rather my personal guess. I just noticed that huge amount of Stirling-number-related formulas have clear and easy combinatorial proof, that's all.