# Inequality with Stirling's numbers of the second kind

Tags: inequality, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof strategy - Stirling numbers formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118029/proof-strategy-stirling-numbers-formula)

Prove inequality:

$ \left\{\begin{array}{c}n\\k-1\end{array}\right\}\left\{\begin{array}{c}n\\k+1\end{array}\right\} \le \left\{\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right\}^2$

for $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$, where $\left\{\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right\}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

I think induction is the last resort. I don't know if it will work but I rather want to avoid it.